# How to de/serialize System.Drawing.Size to object using JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Sample class that I use:

```
class MyClass
{

    private Size _size = new Size(0, 0);

    [DataMember]
    public Size Size
    {
        get { return _size; }
        set { _size = value; }
    }
}
```

This getting serialized to `{size: "0, 0"}`. What I need is `{size: {width: 0, height: 0}}`.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I would probably create a proxy type exposed as a DataMember that serializes as desired, and then hide the real Size object. It's a simple hack, but it works in a jiffy without needing to create a [*Custom Converter*](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) - of course, a converter has the advantage of not needing to overbend the POCOs, so it really depends what the scope of the type is. If it's only used as a JSON DTO, I'd have no problem altering it, but that's not appropriate if the type is used elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simple [`JsonConverter`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/?topic=html/AllMembers_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) you can use to make `System.Drawing.Size` serialize the way you want:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class SizeJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return (objectType == typeof(Size));
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Size size = (Size)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject();
        jo.Add("width", size.Width);
        jo.Add("height", size.Height);
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        return new Size((int)jo["width"], (int)jo["height"]);
    }
}
```

To use the converter, you just need to pass an instance of it to `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` as shown below:

```
MyClass widget = new MyClass { Size = new Size(80, 24) };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(widget, new SizeJsonConverter());
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

This will give the following output:

```
{"Size":{"width":80,"height":24}}
```

Deserialization works the same way; pass an instance of the converter to `DeserializeObject<T>`:

```
string json = @"{""Size"":{""width"":80,""height"":24}}";
MyClass c = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json, new SizeJsonConverter());
Console.WriteLine(c.Size.Width + "x" + c.Size.Height);
```

Output:

```
80x24
```

Comment: Thank you Brian, I just came to the similar solution. But deserialization is not working. `Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Drawing.Size' because the type requires a JSON string value to deserialize correctly.`

Comment: Hmm, it is working for me.  Are you passing the converter to the `DeserializeObject` method?  I added example code to my answer.

Comment: Good but it does change the case of Height and Width to height and width. Not sure this is always desirable

Comment: @apc Just change "height" to "Height" in the converter if that is what you need.  I originally made it lower case because that is what was shown in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Just as a quick add-on to Brian Rogers's answer, in the (somewhat common?) case of the Size being an internal variable inside a larger class you are serializing / de-serializing. This might be trivial, but as I'm new to Newtonsoft's JSON parser, it took me some googling to find the right tag.

Long story short, if your class uses Size as part of it and you'd like to use the above converter. Assume you have the class called Agent that has Size as part of it's definitions, you should do something like this:

```html
public class Agent
{
        [JsonConverter(typeof(SizeJsonConverter))]
        public Size size = new Size();
        public long time_observed = 0;
}
```

Notice that the the tag name is still JsonConverter, but the type of it is the converter sub-class you created from the snippet of the accepted answer.

Hope that saves some newbie like me a few minutes of Googling.

Answer (score -1):

You can use JsonProperty, instead of force each individual property into json result everytime.

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("size")]
    public Size size;
}
```

And this is your Size class

```
public class Size
{
    public Size(int w, int h)
    {
        this.Width = w;
        this.Height = h;
    }

    [JsonProperty("width")]
    public int Width
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [JsonProperty("height")]
    public int Height
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And this is how you access it

```
        MyClass w = new MyClass{ size = new Size(5, 7) };
        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(w);
```

This is what you get

```
{"Size":{"width":5,"height":7}}
```

This way, everytime you add new property in your Size class or even MyClass class, you just need put the JsonProperty attribute on top of it.

Comment: The `Size` in question is the .NET `System.Drawing.Size` struct, not a custom class.