# Unable to serialize a datatype "Size" in c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class named MyInfo.It has a property of Size datatype

```
public class MyInfo{
  private Size position;
  public Size Position
    {
        get { return position; }
        set { position = value; }
    }
 }
```

In my controller i assign it value coming from a service like this

```
MyInfo myInfo = new MyInfo();
resp = myservice.GetDataFromService(id);
dynamic myInfoObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(resp);
var myWidth =(int) myInfoObj.PhysicalSize.Width;
var myHeight =(int) myInfoObj.PhysicalSize.Height;
myInfo.Position= new Size(myWidth, myHeight);
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myInfo);            
return json;
```

When I serialize this data from the service and render it as Json on the UI.I get it in below format

```
"Position":"258, 387"
```

whereas I desire to get in below format. Where am i going wrong?

```
"Position":{"Width":258,"Height":387}
```

Comment: What does the 'Size' class look like?

Comment: size is a built in data type. it is provided by System.drawing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ahh ok, looks like similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471404/how-to-de-serialize-system-drawing-size-to-object-using-json-net

Comment: The reason the `Size` serialized as a string with two numbers is that it has its own `TypeConverter`, namely [`SizeConverter`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/SizeConverter.cs).  The solution is to create the `JsonConverter` shown in @Asnivor's linked answer.

Comment: @dbc thanks you But i was solve my problem by creating a size structure with width and height property. Seemed a faster way around